# disable glow effect of gtkbutton

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I would like to know that how to disable the glow effect of gtkButton on mouseover.
Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following Python code will make a copy of the button's style, set the background color in the `gtk.STATE_PRELIGHT` (mouseover) state to the same color as `gtk.STATE_NORMAL`, and then set the style back on the widget.

```
import gtk

window = gtk.Dialog()
button = gtk.Button('Click Me')

style = button.get_style().copy()
style.bg[gtk.STATE_PRELIGHT] = style.bg[gtk.STATE_NORMAL]
button.set_style(style)

window.vbox.pack_start(button)
window.show_all()
window.run()
```

Since this doesn't mess with the actual state of the button, there are no side effects to the rest of your code.

This code MAY have the an affect on GDK themes. If I discover a theme-safe method for this I will edit my answer.

Comment: To avoid the gdk themeing issue *maybe* I found a solution: you could apply the style after the widget is realized. Use `widget.connect('realize', function)` and then add a function that does the style copy/edit/apply method.

Answer (score 2):

This may be what you are looking for. It is c++, but hopefully you can translate it to the python equivalent. The code changes the background color of a widget in different states.

```
void changeColor(Gtk::Widget* widget, double r, double g, double b) {
    Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Colormap> colormap = widget->get_colormap();
    Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Style> style = widget->get_style()->copy();

    // STATE_NORMAL (most of the time)
    {
        Gdk::Color color;
        color.set_rgb_p(r,g,b);         // <-- customize this
        colormap->alloc_color(color);
        style->set_bg(Gtk::STATE_NORMAL, color);
    }

    // STATE_PRELIGHT (when mouse hovers)
    {
        Gdk::Color color;
        color.set_rgb_p(r*0.9,g*0.9,b*0.9); // <-- customize this
        colormap->alloc_color(color);
        style->set_bg(Gtk::STATE_PRELIGHT, color);
    }

    // STATE_ACTIVE (when clicked)
    {
        Gdk::Color color;
        color.set_rgb_p(r*0.8,g*0.8,b*0.8); // <-- customize this
        colormap->alloc_color(color);
        style->set_bg(Gtk::STATE_ACTIVE, color);
    }

    widget->set_style(style);
}
```

You are interested in setting the right colors in the STATE_PRELIGHT block so that they are the same than in the STATE_NORMAL block. (I'm guessing this is what you mean with your question).

By the way, there are two other states which are not handled in the method above: STATE_SELECTED and STATE_INSENSITIVE. It must also be stated that this function, despite its name, doesn´t actually change the color of any widget. It won't change the color of a label, for example, since a label takes the color of it's container. So don't take the function signature too seriously.

Answer (score 0):

```
import gtk

def enter(widget, event):
    widget.set_state(gtk.STATE_NORMAL)
    return False

win = gtk.Dialog()
button = gtk.Button('Button')
button.connect_after('enter-notify-event', enter)
win.vbox.pack_start(button, 0, 0)
win.vbox.show_all()
win.run()
```

Comment: This works, but if the widget's state is important to something else in the code it might cause problems. It might be better to change the style of the button instead.